# Fragment is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, android

I am having a Fragment inside a class, because it's part of a ViewPager.
However, in my outer class, I am implementing and OnItemClickListener from a third part library for NavigationDrawer. But inside my inner class, I have an OnItemClickListener which is the Android SDK interface. But it gives me an error due to a fail of implementing the onItemClick method, which I actually have implemented.

Inner class implementation:

```
public static class AllFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```

implementation of the onItemClick method:

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                String selectedItem;
                if (position % 2 == 0)
                    selectedItem = "Facebook";
                else
                    selectedItem = "Twitter";
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Selected Item: " /*+ GridViewCustomAdapter.titles.get(position)*/,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent showItem = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowAdvert.class);
                showItem.putExtra("objectId", objectIdList.get(position));
                startActivity(showItem);

            }
        });
```

The error:

```
Error:(327, 16) error: AllFragment is not abstract and does not override abstract method onItemClick(AdapterView<?>,View,int,long) in OnItemClickListener
```

If I don't write `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` but just write `new OnItemClickListener()`instead, it will call the OnItemClickListener from the outer class, which I'm not interested in. Btw the outer class start looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends NavigationLiveo implements
    br.liveo.interfaces.OnItemClickListener {
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: There is no relationship between the `onItemClick` method in that anonymous class and `AllFragment`. You need to implement the method in `AllFragment`, or remove the `implements` from that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you made your fragment class implements the Listener but you did not have a method that implements it.

You should override the method as a method in your fragment class, or, you can simply remove the implements for your fragment class, since you are already overriding the method in your anonymous class.

```
public static class AllFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    // constructor and methods
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                int position, long arg3) {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

And then assign the Listener to the GridView

```
gridView.setOnClickListener(this)
```